# Arithmetic operation on String in makefile without Shell utility

Tags: windows, math, makefile, operation

I want to perform Arithmetic operation on string variable, I don't have shell utility in makefile system platform for i386-pc-mingw32 (windows).
Can anybody help me how to perform Arithmetic operation( substraction , comparsion ) on string variable by any means ??

Comment: Do you have `bc`? `dc`?

Comment: no i dont have bc dc utility of shell

Comment: my makefile is for i386-pc-mingw32

Comment: What shell are you using? You are limiting yourself to the shell since any lines not interpreted as makefile statements are passed to the shell, so the answer will depend upon your choice/requirement of shell. In any case, you will most likely be limited to integer arithmetic (1/2=0, not 0.5) because most shells don't do floating point operations. Depending on what you want, you may need a separate utility such as `bc`, `python`, `perl`, `awk`, etc.

Comment: Regarding comparison, that (again) depends on your shell and whether it has a built-in way to compare two values. If you're on Windows, maybe you have Powershell? If so, that may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

To add a late answer: The [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) features (in spite of its name) many arithmetic functions. You can add, subtract, multiply, divide, take the modulus in base 8,10 and 16. Also there are the usual binary operations and, or, xor and not. Numbers can be around 60 digits but you can adapt this, if you need more. The code is pure GNUmake syntax and therefore portable between Windows and Unix, contrary to shell scripts - in case you want to number crunch, there may be better solutions ;) of course.

Here is an example:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

NUMBER_A := -12392834798732429827442389
NUMBER_B := 984398723982791273498234
$(info $(call add,$(NUMBER_A),$(NUMBER_B)))
$(info $(call sub,$(NUMBER_A),$(NUMBER_B)))
$(info $(call mul,$(NUMBER_A),$(NUMBER_B)))
$(info $(call div,$(NUMBER_A),$(NUMBER_B)))
$(info $(call mod,$(NUMBER_A),$(NUMBER_B)))
```

Output:

```
$ make
-11408436074749638553944155
-13377233522715221100940623
-12199490762401735834920873237276176262117128241026
-12
-580050110938934545463581
```